# How is the status tag implemented in Doug Lea's malloc?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

### Background

The malloc the GNU C Library uses is essentially [Doug Lea's malloc implementation](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) (also known as *dlalloc*), extended for multi-threading support.

### Question

Here's an image describing how "chunks" work in *dlalloc*:

[image]

As you can see, two things seem to be stored in the same space at the beginning of each chunk: **size** and **status**.

How does this work? Are they stored right next to each other in contiguous memory, or are they somehow both stored in the same location and accessed with bitmasking?

Answer (score 4):

`size` is a number of bytes that is a multiple of some alignment value (8 or 16).  The low order bits are used for flags, collectively referred to as `status`.  The various functions mask off the status bits to get the size information.  In some special cases. the status bit are known to be all `0`, so the masking operation is omitted.